# Can a birational morphism between two smooth varieties of the same betti numbers exist?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I am considering a birational morphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective varieties and I want to deform $X$ to another given smooth projective $Z$. It is given that $X$ and $Z$ have the same betti numbers (in fact, their integral cohomology groups are isomorphic as abelian groups to that of the product of several copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$'s). However, the cup products of these groups do not quite match, and hence $X$ and $Z$ are not diffeomorphic.

To remedy this problem, I try to find an intermediate variety $X'$ between $X$ and $Y$, namely a factorisation of $f$ into two other birational morphisms $f:X\xrightarrow{g} X'\xrightarrow{h} Y$ and deform $X'$ to $Z$ instead of $X$.

My question is: A necessary condition for this to be possible is that $X$ and $X'$ have the same betti numbers. I would like to ask if there is any existing examples of such $g$ or any obvious reason that its existence is impossible.

Comment: A birational morphism between smooth projective varieties with the same Betti numbers must be an isomorphism: $f_* \circ f^*$ is an isomorphism on integral cohomology but if a positive dimensional subvariety is contracted by $f$ then its fundamental class would be in the kernel of $f_*$.

Comment: Thank you @ulrich. I understand your arguments except that $f_*\circ f^*$ is an isomorphism on integral cohomology of the target variety. Is it a standard fact about birational morphisms?

Comment: Yes. It follows from the projection formula: the main point is that $f_*(1_X) = 1_Y$, where $1_X$ (resp. $1_Y$) is the unit in $H^0(X)$ (resp. $H^0(Y)$).